# parameters of glGenTexture?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, parameters

It sounds simple, but I looked on various sites and it gives me only two parameters :

```
void glGenTextures(GLsizei n, GLuint * textures)
```

.. with explaination.

However when using OpenGL ES with android, that method doesn't exist, and I also saw multiple websites, source codes and tutorials using this method with three parameters, which for me doesn't give me a compiler error :

```
gl.glGenTextures(amountOfTexturesToMake, pointerToArray, 0);
```

.. what's that zero for? What is that third parameter ? Even tough I saw various people using it, I couldn't find a explaination of it .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The offset parameter specifies the starting index in the int array. It's a way to 'emulate' pointer arithemic.

the following

```
glGenTextures(n, (texture + offset))
```

could be "translated" to

```
gl.glGenTextures(n, textureArray, offset)
```

Comment: So if i'm going to generate multiple texture names, with multiple calls, I'd have keep a int variable of the index it's currently at ,And if a new name is created do something like: index++ ?

Comment: It will depend on textureArray scope. But if you plan to keep your texture names in textureArray throughout the application yes.

Comment: I'm curious to know **how** you know that. All I see in [the documentation for glGenTextures](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLES20#glGenTextures(int,%20int[],%20int)) is that the argument is called `offset`, but there's no supporting text description of what the argument means.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it's the array offset, i.e., the index where the first texture name (ID) is stored.